# Change Salesforce date format when tagging from DocusIGN

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

We've just started using DocuSign and have a query regarding the date format that is being pulled through from a Date field in Salesforce.

One of our custom tags is related to the field Opportunity.Agreement_Date__c which shows in Saleforce as DD/MM/YYYY however, when showing on the DocuSign it shows as YYYY/MM/DD. Is there a way I can align these or even decide what format is showing in DocuSign.

Apologies in advance if this is the wrong place to ask!

Thanks,

Alastair

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce displays the dates, times and numbers according to user's locale. Any user can change his locale in Setup -> My personal information and the list of supported locales is here: http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_supported_locales.htm. Locale is independent from user's language and timezone but you might have hard time finding one that you feel comfortable with.

I have no idea what you can do on the DocuSign end, you might have to go through their documentation.

On top of locales and default display modes if you're using Apex, Visualforce or formula fields you have further options to format dates however you want. In Apex your best bet would be [Date](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_date.htm) and [DateTime](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) methods reference, in Visualforce - check out [apex:outputText](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm)... This would be of any use to you only if you can somehow fetch raw data from them and display it yourself.